# How do I insert multiple columns into a table using OUTPUT in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, output-clause

Scroll down to the OUTPUT part. It's giving me a red underline.  I want to insert into the `InsertedCreditDebitAdjustmentIDs` table, the ID inserted into `@CreditDebitAdjustment` along with the InvoiceNum. How do I go about doing this?

```
DECLARE @InsertedCreditDebitAdjustmentIDs TABLE
(
  ID INT,
  InvoiceNumber VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @CreditDebitAdjustment ( col1, col2, ...)
SELECT  @ImportedFileID AS '@ImportedFileID', 
  tbl.col.value('(Purpose/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(500)') AS Purpose,
  etc.
FROM @XML.nodes('/CreditDebitAdjustments/CreditDebitAdjustment') AS tbl (col)
OUTPUT INSERTED.CreditDebitAdjustmentID, etc. INTO @InsertedCreditDebitAdjustmentIDs
```

Comment: Here is an example I wrote up : http://granadacoder.wordpress.com/2008/12/10/sqlserver20052008-output-clause-in-insertupdatedelete-statements/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

put your `OUTPUT clause` right after you `INSERT INTO` statement something lie this....

```
INSERT INTO TableName (Column1, Column2, Column3.....)
OUTPUT inserted.Column1 , inserted.Column2 INTO @TableName
SELECT  Column1, Column2, Column3.....
FROM Table_name
```

On a side note I would suggest you to keep `XML Shredding` and your `INSERT` operations in separate statements. any hanky panky in your XML can leave you with a lot of cleaning to do :)

do the shredding separately insert results into a temp table, once happy then insert into your target tables.

Comment: what if I wanna do a where clause? This isn't working: OUTPUT INSERTED.RetailImportOrderID,
            INSERTED.ErrorMessage
   WHERE INSERTED.ErrorMessage  = 'Nothing has changed. The order is 100% duplicated.'
            INTO @DeletablePODuplicates

Comment: if i remove the where clause from above, it does work.

Comment: you cannot use WHERE clause with OUTPUT, if you want to limit the rows you should use where clause in your select statement

Comment: @Rj. or once you have inserted data into your TableName  through output, you can use where clause when selecting data from it again. OUTPUT clause doesnt allow you to limit the rows using where clause.

Answer (score 1):

It goes:

```
TARGET (insert/update etc.)
OUTPUT (direct or into another table)
SOURCE (select/values etc.)
```

So you just need to switch the order:

```
INSERT dbo.tablename(column1, column2, ...)
OUTPUT INSERTED.col1, INSERTED.col2, ... [INTO ...]
SELECT @var1, col1, etc. FROM elsewhere...
```

See the [OUTPUT Clause (Transact-SQL) documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) for examples.